# javascript: anonymous function expose functions (how frameworks really works)

Tags: javascript

i was exploring in the last few days how big frameworks works , how they assign their function name and it can't(?) be override , i pretty much know how framework work with anonymous function , for example they do it this way or similar version :

```
(function(){
   var Sizzle = function (){
      var x;
   };
   Sizzle.f = function(){
     alert("!");
   };

   window.Sizzle = Sizzle;

})();
```

i still don't get few things about those huge frameworks and i hope i can find answer :

1. how do they assign function name and the name can't be override?
2. in the code above to call the function i need to write Sizzle.f() to get the function to work , but when i use jquery i don't write Jquery.show() , just show() , how do they vanish the "jquery" from "jquery.show()" function call?

by saying the name can't be override i mean , if i create function with one of the jquery functions names , the jquery function will work.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your numbered questions do not make sense. (1) What do you mean by _"the name can't be override?"_ (2) What do you mean by _"when I use jQuery I [just write] `show()`"_ and what do you mean by _"vanish the 'jQuery' from the function call?"_ What function call are you referring to? It would be great if you could clarify these in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: I think you may be confused by some concepts and/or applications of concepts. See @Matt Ball's comment and request.

Comment: This refutes your first point: http://jsfiddle.net/kM9U3/1/ And you'll need to provide an example of the second, since unless it's a globally-scoped function, you can't call it the way you suggest, certainly not a jQuery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been shown for #2, it's really easy for BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff to be added to anything you want.

```
var _ = BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff;
_(); // runs BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff;
```

As for #1:

Most libraries *DO* let their functions be overwritten.
It's the values that are inside of the framework's closure which are preserved, for safety reasons.

So you could do something like:

```
BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff = function StealEverything() {};
(BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff === StealEverything) // true;
```

But doStuff would have NO access to any of the variables hidden inside of the framework's closure.
It would also mean that until the page was reloaded, doStuff would also not work the way you want it to.

HOWEVER, in newer versions of JavaScript (ECMA5-compatible browsers), it WILL be possible to do something like what you're suggesting.

```
BIG_NAMESPACE = (function () {
    var do_stuff = function () { console.log("doin' stuff"); },
        functions = {
            set doStuff (overwrite) { }
            get doStuff () { return do_stuff; }
        };
    return { Functions : functions };
}());
```

Then, this will work:

```
BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff(); // "doin' stuff"
BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff = function () { console.log("ain't doin' jack"); };
BIG_NAMESPACE.Functions.doStuff(); // "doin' stuff"
```

However, Frameworks aren't going to use this for a *LONG* time.
This is not even remotely backwards compatible.  Maybe in 2016...
There were *defineGetter*  and *defineSetter* methods as well, but they aren't a formal part of the JavaScript language.  Like innerHTML, they're things that the browser vendors put in, to make life better...  ...as such, there's no real guarantee that they're going to be in any/all browsers your users have.  Plus, they're deprecated, now that new browsers use the get and set constructs that other languages have.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){

var jqueree = {};
jqueree.someval = 22;

jqueree.somefunc = function(){ alert(this.someval); };

window.jqueree = jqueree;

window.somefunc = function(){ jqueree.somefunc.call(jqueree); };

window.$$$ = jqueree;

})();

// all equivalent
window.somefunc();
window.jqueree.somefunc();
$$$.somefunc();
somefunc();
```

Comment: i can be able to do it this way? window.MYAPI = jqueree; ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answering your Questions

1. At the top of jQuery you'll see:  `var jQuery = (function() {`, which creates the local function (*its incomplete; the `});` occurs elsewhere*).

   At the very end of jQuery you'll notice the following, which is how it attaches it to the global namespace:

   ```
      // Expose jQuery to the global object
      window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
   ```
2. I have never seen a jQuery function called without referencing the jQuery object.  I think you always need to use `jQuery.show()` or `$.show()`; however maybe you're saying you don't have to call `window.jQuery.show()`, which you are permitted to drop the `window`, since that is the default.

---

#### Using your example

```
(function(){

   /* This is where Sizzle is defined locally, but not exposed globally     */
   var Sizzle = function (){
      var x;
   };

   /* If you put "window.f = Sizzle.f = function(){" then you could         *
    * call f() w/o typing Sizzle.f()                                        */
   Sizzle.f = function(){
     alert("!");
   };

   /*  The following line is what makes it so you can use Sizzle elsewhere  *
    *  on your page (it exposes it globally here)                           */
   window.Sizzle = Sizzle;  

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `function _name_() {}` and the name is static
2. the simply use `var $ = jQuery;` to create an alias.

Comment: What do you mean by #1? In JavaScript, `static` has a meaning that is different from how you use the word here. Please clarify.

Comment: can you go a little further and add explanations ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works this way:

Supposed you have this jQuery code:

```
$("#title").show();
```

You have three elements to that line.

1. `$` is a javascript function
2. `"#title"` is an argument to that function
3. `.show()` is a method call

Here's how it works.

- Javascript executes the function named `$` and passed it an argument of `"#title"`.
- That function does it's business, finds the `#title` object in the DOM, creates a jQuery object, puts that DOM element into the array in the jQuery object and returns the jQuery object.
- The Javascript execution engine then takes the return value from that function call (which is now a jQuery object) and looks for and executes the `.show()` method on that object.
- The `.show()` method then looks at the array of DOM elements in the jQuery object and does the show operation for each DOM element.

In answer to your question, there is no `.show()` all by itself.  It's a method on a jQuery object and, in this example, that jQuery object is returned from the `$("#title")` function call.